# Is the variable that holds a reference to an object a value type?

Tags: c#, .net

You've got a simple class:

```
public class foo {
    public object Property { get; set; }

    public void AMethod() {
        Property = new object();
        object x = Property;
    }
}
```

As we know, the Property property has a hidden backing field that holds the object reference. The question is: is that backing field treated like a struct?

What I mean is the memory for x allocated on the stack? Does it get garbage collected?  Or is it released when the method returns?

**EDIT**

I'm responding here instead of in a comment because the text is too long to fit in a comment.

I'm interested in x. I'm not aware of any class in the .Net framework called "ObjectReference". All anyone talks about is "I have a reference to an object", and you call the methods of the object using the reference.

The fact is, the reference to the object and the object itself are not 1 & the same thing. They both occupy different chunks of memory. When you pass an object to a method as a parameter, you're not passing the object but a reference to it. That reference is copied from an "ObjectReference" variable to the stack.

References are extremely important. You can't manipulate an object without one; even "this" (or the implied "this" when you access the object's members inside of it) are really references to the particular chunk of memory that the object occupies.

I don't think many people give any thought to references as separate entities. They're ubiquitous and you can't get anything done with objects without them.

So what I'm trying to get at here is, if there were an ObjectReference class, would it be a struct? It seems like the memory for the reference itself is treated like a struct.

Comment: x is released when the method goes out of scope. x was basically holding a reference to the object/value currently stored in Property.

Comment: Are you asking about `x` or `Property`? Or the hidden backing field of `Property`?

Comment: You obviously know that `struct` and "allocated on the stack" are completely unrelated... just checking... (My back of the envelope estimate would be 33% of all `struct` allocated on the heap)

Comment: The question is not very clear... And the hidden backing field has essentially the same behaviour that you would get if you manually declare the field and use it from your property.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yes, I know. Structs can be used as members of objects, which means that the memory for them will be allocated on the heap. That's not what I'm getting at. What I'm trying to get at is: do references follow struct semantics or what?

Answer (score 2):

> What I mean is the memory for `x` allocated on the stack?

Yes, the memory for `x`, which holds the reference to `object`, is allocated on the stack - very much like a pointer in languages that have them.

> Does it get garbage collected? Or is it released when the method returns?

The memory for the reference itself is released immediately as soon as the method returns. If `x` is the last live reference to its object, then the referenced object becomes eligible for garbage collection.